# Work with a JSON map in tiled?

Tags: json, xml, tiled

I have a problem with Tiled...

When I create a map it's all correct, I SAVE IT IN TO A JSON FILE, I try the map in my game.. all correct.. The problem is that when I try to open the map again with Tiled, It says that He can't open the map.

Is it because I saved it in to a JSON File?
I don't know how to use XML, so I can only work with JSON, but I want to do some changes to the map sometimes!!

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

That may be a bug in Tiled. Please open an issue about it at https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/issues, mentioning the exact error message and preferably providing the JSON file so that I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: Okk!! I'll post it now